# SQL Select 1 column From 2 Tables into 1 tables

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables

tbl 1

ID

1
  2
 3

tbl 2

```
level
```

lvl 1
 lvl 2
  lvl 3

i need

```
id | level
```

1  | level 1
2  | level 2
3  | level 3

Comment: Are there any other fields in tbl2?

Comment: You haven't defined a foreign key in tbl2. You could do a join on a substring of tbl2.level, but that's a violation of codd laws.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have phrased the question, the second table is not necessary.  You can just concatenate the values together:

```
select id, concat('level ', cast(id as varchar(255))) as level
from t
```

In some databases, you might use the `||` or `+` operator instead of `concat()`.

Comment: Then you will get `'level 20'` as "level".

Comment: @AngeloCreerBisquera . . . You should probably ask another question, giving better examples of sample data and the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, [level] 
from tbl1 
cross join tbl2
where CHARINDEX(cast(id as varchar),[level],0) > 0
```